# Stereo Camera Rectification using saved parameters

Tags: c++, opencv

im using intrinsics and extrinsics files from my calibration of my camera to rectify my image pair so i can make a better depth map, but every time i try to run my program. my depth map output only shows blank.

here is the code of my rectification:

```cpp
    FileStorage fs("intrinsics.yml", FileStorage::READ);
    fs["intrisics"] >> intrinsics;

    Mat M1, D1, M2, D2;
    fs["M1"] >> M1;
    fs["D1"] >> D1;
    fs["M2"] >> M2;
    fs["D2"] >> D2;

    M1 *= scale;
    M2 *= scale;

    fs.open("extrinsics.yml", FileStorage::READ);
    fs["extrinsics"] >> extrinsics;

    Mat R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2;
    fs["R"] >> R;
    fs["T"] >> T;
    fs["R1"] >> R1;
    fs["R2"] >> R2;
    fs["P1"] >> P1;
    fs["P2"] >> P2;
    fs["Q"] >> Q;
    stereoRectify(M1, D1, M2, D2, img_size, R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q, 0, -1, img_size, &roi1, &roi2);

    Mat map11, map12, map21, map22;
    initUndistortRectifyMap(M1, D1, R1, P1, img_size, CV_32FC1, map11, map12);
    initUndistortRectifyMap(M2, D2, R2, P2, img_size, CV_32FC1, map21, map22);

    Mat img1r, img2r;
    remap(grayL, img1r, map11, map12, INTER_LINEAR);
    remap(grayR, img2r, map21, map22, INTER_LINEAR);
```

My SGBM code:

```cpp
    Ptr<StereoSGBM> sgbm = StereoSGBM::create
    (0,    //int minDisparity
        96,     //int numDisparities
        5,      //int SADWindowSize
        600,    //int P1 = 0
        2400,   //int P2 = 0
        20,     //int disp12MaxDiff = 0
        16,     //int preFilterCap = 0
        1,      //int uniquenessRatio = 0
        100,    //int speckleWindowSize = 0
        20,     //int speckleRange = 0
        true);  //bool fullDP = false

    sgbm->compute(img1r, img2r, disparity_sgbm);

    normalize(disparity_sgbm, disp_done_sgbm, 0, 255, CV_MINMAX, CV_8U);
```

everytime i calibrate my camera and running my program works and gives decent depth map. but the stereo pair is not aligned because its not rectified. calibrating my camera takes few hours so im trying to just load the parameters of my camera so i dont have to calibrate for hours every time to get a decent depth map

Thank you in advance!

Here are my outputs:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ajS3vgoVPx2RgbroV8qH2WYHU85PL_SJ-9A4q8aa8e8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The rectification process seems ok, is it possibly something wrong with your data?
I suggest to make sure that your rectification inputs are loaded with no error and the remapping step gives the right row-aligned stereo pairs.

Comment: i used the opencv sample code of stereo camera calibration to get my intrinsic and extrinsic parameters. i did get an average error of 1.5 with 150 image pairs.